# Finding discrete logarithm of composite numbers

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, discrete-logarithms

I started to learn discete logarithm the definition says that:suppose that "p" is a prime number , "r" is a primitive  root  (modulo p) and "a" is an integer between "1 and p-1" inclusive.If  r^e (modp)=a and "e" is in [0,p-1] then the "e" is discrete logarithm of "a modulo p" to the base "r".

However, when I search in google, i encountered a discrete logarithm calculator.When i get the inputs into it, it gave unexpected results.For example, i wrote that 3^x(mod10)=7 and it results that x is 3.It was true but there was a contradiction with definition because 10 is not a prime number.The other exaple is that 3^x(mod11)=5, the contradictions with definition are that 3 is not primitive root(generator) of 11.However,the calculator answered it correctly such that x is 3.

My question is that is there any deficiency in my definition or is the calculator wrong ?Moreover, if my definition is correct , why did calculator answer the questions correctly? and can composite numbers have discrete log

Comment: Some composites have primitive roots.  $3$ is a primitive root $\mod {10}$ since the powers of $3$ form a complete set of the residues prime to $10$ $\pmod {10}$.

Comment: @lulu you mean the ones coprime to $10$.  $2$ and $5$, for example, are not included.

Comment: @RobertIsrael  Absolutely. I'll edit the comment accordingly.  Thanks!

Comment: @RobertIsrael  thanks for your helps.Then , the is not any restriction for composite numbers to have a discrete logarithm

Comment: @lulu thanks for your helps

Comment: To be clear:  most composites do not have primitive roots.  $8$ does not have a primitive root, for example.

Comment: @lulu yes, i know it, but my question is not as to exactly primitive roots.My question was that is there any deficiency in my definiton because for modulo=10,base=3 and exponent=7 the discrete log=3.However it conradicted with dfinition because modulo p was not prime

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The basic definition is that if $r^e \equiv a \mod n$, $e$ is a discrete logarithm of $a$ mod $n$ to base $r$.  The theory is simpler if $n$ is a prime and $r$ is a primitive root mod $a$, but there is no reason not to consider the problem when $n$ is composite and $r$ is not a primitive root.  Of course existence may not be guaranteed.